# JavaScript - Readmore.js - Method is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am attempting to implement [readmore.js](https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js/tree/version-3.0) into my code but I am continuously running into `readmore.js is not a function` error. I've read over the documentation multiple times and I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. When implemented correctly should include a "READ MORE" button to expand the text in its entirety.

1. I've included the HTML script tag that is presented in the github
2. I've made sure I included a jquery cdn before the readmore.js
3. I've included a class name of `article`
4. I've attempted to wrap the `.readmore` in a function such as :

   `$(function () { $('.article').readmore({speed: 75, lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less</a>'});});`

Here is a snippet of code that I am working with:

```js
const data = [{ paragraph: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis id aliquam nibh. Aenean a porttitor ipsum. Vestibulum ut sagittis dui, nec pharetra eros. Vivamus tempus fringilla dictum. Maecenas facilisis auctor magna, a accumsan nunc molestie dictum. In tempus rhoncus condimentum. Aenean interdum leo et velit pellentesque dapibus. Vivamus nunc orci, commodo sit amet dui a, lobortis finibus arcu. Maecenas metus mauris, tincidunt sit amet ex id, gravida commodo nunc. Donec consequat tristique lacinia. Pellentesque commodo eu tortor sit amet rutrum. Vivamus mollis eros ipsum, in vestibulum lorem tempor sit amet. Morbi egestas orci sem, posuere rutrum augue malesuada eget. Mauris ultricies egestas luctus. Praesent at dignissim nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat."},{
paragraph: "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam porttitor tincidunt fringilla. In ullamcorper vitae sapien eget ornare. Nulla quis lacus condimentum lacus tincidunt consectetur ut in ante. Suspendisse a eleifend est. Pellentesque eu ornare magna. Vestibulum ac mi sit amet arcu tristique volutpat in id nisl. Aenean interdum et odio gravida hendrerit. Pellentesque at diam lacus. Mauris elementum ultricies imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus metus ligula, molestie at laoreet id, convallis et felis. Nullam molestie, augue vel interdum semper, dui massa feugiat risus, non sodales est massa non arcu. Vivamus ut sodales metus."
}
]

let htmlOutput = ""

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   htmlOutput += "<div>" + data[i].paragraph + "</div>"
}

$("#report").html(htmlOutput)

$('.article').readmore({
    speed: 75,
    lessLink: '<a href="#">Read less</a>'
});
```

```html
<div id="report" class="article">

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/readmore-js/readmore.min.js"></script>
```

My expected outcome is to be able to include the `.readmore` function and have a "read more" that will expand the text once clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to download the readmore.min.js file from the repo. The file is located here.

https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js/blob/master/readmore.min.js

Then you can include it in your project by putting it in the same directory as your index.html file and add a script tag like this

`<script src="readmore.min.js"></script>`

Comment: On my local, my script tags are at the bottom as you suggested but I still run into the error. I've tried moving it below in the code snippet above and I am still getting the `.readmore is not a function`

Comment: do you have a node_modules folder in your project?

Comment: No I do not, I just simply copied the script tag from the github is that a requirment?

Comment: Sorry - you can also go to the repository and download the readmore.min.js file located here https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js/blob/master/readmore.min.js and include it in your project and reference that file in your script tags.

Comment: Hey @Marco I appreciate your help, including the .js file did get rid of my error but still has no effect on my code itself, my container appears normal without a "read more" option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220643/discussion-between-marco-chavez-and-stepheniok).

Answer (score 0):

hi this might have been solved but ill add my 2c.

from your code it seem that you are adding the text inside a nested div instead of the parent div with the article class.

try adding `"id='report' class= 'article' "` inside the for loop div and check if the plugin works